# What minimum permissions requires to execute an undocumented stored procedure called SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL?

Tags: db2, ddl, user-permissions, db2-luw

I don't want to execute the stored procedure with admin privileges or with the instance owner. I am looking for the minimum permissions required to execute an undocumented stored procedure called `SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL` for extracting the DDL statements from a DB2 database.

For example: I tried with `SELECT` and `EXCEUTE` permissions but it's not working:

```
db2 grant SELECT on SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO to user devuser

db2 grant execute on procedure SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL to user devuser`
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not very helpful statement to understand the problem. What's the exact error message you get on what exact statement?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call this routine once as some administrative user with appropriate privileges to create necessary objects implicitly in the database.
Grant the following privileges to your user afterwards.

```
grant usage on sequence SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_TOKEN to user myuser;
grant select on table SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO_V to user myuser;
grant select, update, delete, insert on table SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO to user myuser;
```